# Using only a fraction of a very large pre-allocated array

Tags: memory-management, fortran, allocation

When we allocate an array in Fortran or C, my understanding is that the memory is first allocated in the so-called virtual memory, while the physical memory is allocated only when we write data onto (some part of) the array (e.g., based on this [page](http://www.darkcoding.net/software/resident-and-virtual-memory-on-linux-a-short-example/)). Does this mean that, if we allocate a very large array (say 10^9 elements) and use only a fraction of it (say the first 10^6 elements), do we need only the physical memory for the latter? If so, is it practically no problem to utilize this feature to accommodate data of unknown (but not too large) size in a very large, pre-allocated array?

For example, the following Fortran code first allocates a large array of size 10^9, write data onto the first 10^6 elements, and perform reallocation to adjust the array size.

```
integer, allocatable :: a(:)
integer :: nlarge, nsmall, i

nlarge = 1000000000  !! 10^9
nsmall =    1000000  !! 10^6 

allocate( a( nlarge ) )   !! allocate in virtual memory

print *, "after allocation"
call system( "ps aux | grep a.out" )

do i = 1, nsmall
    a( i ) = i     !! write actual data (we assume that "nsmall" is not known a priori)
enddo

print *, "after assignment"
call system( "ps aux | grep a.out" )

a = a( 1 : nsmall )    !! adjust the array size by reallocation

print *, "after reallocation"
call system( "ps aux | grep a.out" )
```

The output on my machine (Linux x86_64 with gfortran) is

```
after allocation
username    29064  0.0  0.0 3914392  780 pts/3    S+   01:15   0:00 ./a.out
after assignment
username    29064  0.0  0.0 3914392 5188 pts/3    S+   01:15   0:00 ./a.out
after reallocation
username    29064  0.0  0.0  12048  4692 pts/3    S+   01:15   0:00 ./a.out
```

which shows that only ~5 MB of physical memory is used. Is it possible to utilize this feature to accommodate temporary data of unknown size (but below physical-memory size)?

**Edit**

To be more specific, my supposed system is a typical workstation running Linux x86_64 (e.g. CentOS) with tens of GB RAM, and the program is written in Fortran. The motivation for the Question is that, when I wish to store data of unknown size into an array, I usually need to know its size somehow and allocate an array appropriately. However, this approach is a bit tedious unless we have a built-in dynamic array. Typically, this situation occurs in two cases: (1) When one reads data from an external file that contains data of unknown size; and (2) when one collects data that match specific conditions over multi-dimensional loops. In case 1, we typically scan a file twice (once to get the data size and next to read the data), or alternatively pre-allocate a sufficiently large array as a buffer. So, I was interested in whether the virtual memory system helps simplify this task by allowing an allocation of very large arrays (without caring too much about the size).

However, from more experiment I got to know that this approach is rather limited... For example, if I change the size of arrays as follows, `ifort` complains about "insufficient virtual memory" above ~80 GB, which corresponds probably to the sum of physical memory + swap region on my system. So, although "ulimit -a" says that virtual memory is "unlimited", it seems not unlimited in practice...

```
! compiled with: ifort -heap-arrays -assume realloc_lhs 
use iso_fortran_env, only: long => int64
integer, allocatable :: a(:)
integer(long) :: nlarge, nsmall, i

! nlarge = 10_long**9   !! OK: 4 GB                                              
! nlarge = 10_long**10   !! OK: 40 GB                                            
nlarge = 2 * 10_long**10   !! OK: 80 GB                                         
! nlarge = 3 * 10_long**10   !! NG: insufficient virtual memory (120 GB)         
! nlarge = 4 * 10_long**10   !! NG: insufficient virtual memory (160 GB)         
! nlarge = 10_long**11    ! NG: insufficient virtual memory (400 GB)             

nsmall = 10**6   !! 4 MB
```

Conclusion: It seems better to use the traditional approaches (i.e., allocate an array with necessary size, or re-allocate an allocatable array repeatedly as needed, or utilize a user-defined dynamic array). I'm sorry for this trivial conclusion...

Comment: 1) The question is too broad. Ask about **one** language. 2) You are confusing very different things. C does not even mention how memory is managed. I'd strongly recommend some reading about what the terms actually mean.

Comment: @Olaf I am sorry for including two languages. I was interested in whether this kind of thing is common for different languages, i.e., essentially determined by the OS (in my case, Linux x86_64). And yes, my understanding about memory is very poor (just experimenting by looking at [this page](http://www.darkcoding.net/software/resident-and-virtual-memory-on-linux-a-short-example/) etc, so need to learn more...

Comment: Read the language standards.

Comment: A very good paper about memory : https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf . It is a bit old (2007), but still very useful.

Comment: @AnthonyScemama Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When we allocate an array in Fortran or C, my understanding is that the memory is first allocated in the so-called virtual memory, while the physical memory is allocated only when we write data onto (some part of) the array.

That's one thing that your OS **may** chose to do. There's no guarantee it doesn't actually add actual page table entries for all your reserved memory, mapping and thus possessing physical memory.

In fact, C or Fortran don't tell you anything on how you'll get memory, where that'll come from or how the OS handles getting you that memory. You're confusing what your language specifies, how your standard library handles asking for memory and how the underlying OS actually maps physical memory to process address space – in fact, on systems without an MMU (memory management unit), you can run perfectly fine C code, but all memory addresses will actually be physical.

> Does this mean that, if we allocate a very large array (say 10^9 elements) and use only a fraction of it (say the first 10^6 elements), do we need only the physical memory for the latter?

Be a bit careful with that. Again, it's up to the OS to implement that. An OS might (and typically will) implement that "lazy mapping" feature, but still won't give you much more memory than physically available.

Also, remember that at least for 32bit OSes, there are relevant memory space restrictions: A 32bit process can't have more than 2GB of of memory space, meaning that you can't have 10^9 32bit integers at all!

> If so, is it practically no problem to utilize this feature to accommodate data of unknown (but not too large) size in a very large, pre-allocated array?

It is practically a problem, as the OS might just not give you that much memory. Also, there's no real downside of getting more memory later (see the [`realloc` standard C function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc)), aside fromt the time spent then; the OS will have to find free pages and map them into your process space, and possibly remap previous pages.

Comment: Ehm, the standard does not even mention something like virtual memory. If it would, C was useless for embedded systems (and would have been for desktop systems not that long ago). You should clarify more that OP confuses duties of the different layers.

Comment: @Olaf: true. Will clarify.

Comment: It looks better now, but you still imply a "typical OS" will use virtual memory. That is in fact not true. Far by most OSs actually don't. Note that embedded systems are much wider spread than typical PC- or server OSs.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you very much for detailed explanation. So the behavior is highly OS-dependent and it is safer not to assume any similar behavior in general... Because Fortran does not have dynamic arrays that automatically grows, I wondered if I can rely on the virtual memory system, but it seems safer to do reallocation explicitly as needed (from small to large memory). Thanks very much!